# Python UnicodeDecodeError while using modulefinder

Tags: python, unicode, module, python-import, decode

I want to find all imported modules in a python program. I am using the `modulefinder` standard module for my job. I am trying to follow [this example](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/modulefinder.html#example-usage-of-modulefinder) on docs, but I get this error even if I use the same code as the documents:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\Desktop\Deploy\zipperutils\find modules.py", line 4, in <module>
    finder.run_script('bacon.py')
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 165, in run_script
    self.load_module('__main__', fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 360, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 433, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 378, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 177, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 233, in find_head_package
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 326, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 360, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 433, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 378, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 177, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 233, in find_head_package
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 326, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 360, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 433, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 378, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 177, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 233, in find_head_package
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 326, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 360, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 466, in scan_code
    self.scan_code(c, m)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 433, in scan_code
    self._safe_import_hook(name, m, fromlist, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 378, in _safe_import_hook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 177, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 233, in find_head_package
    q = self.import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 326, in import_module
    m = self.load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\modulefinder.py", line 343, in load_module
    co = compile(fp.read()+'\n', pathname, 'exec')
  File "C:\Users\Dinçel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 308: character maps to <undefined>
```

My operating system is Windows 10.

I am using Python3.8.1

If there is a better way of finding imported modules let me know it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Not sure how to fix this, but it's most certainly connected to the paths containing non-ASCII characters. Apparently, Python assumes some 8-bit encoding (maybe Latin-5), but that isn't correct (the paths are encoded differently).

Comment: @lenz Hmm, This came to my mind too. Should I open a bug issue on CPython?

Comment: If you know how the paths are encoded, there might be some environment variable that you could set to tell Python.

Comment: Yes, it is utf-8. Which variable is it?

Comment: Are you sure? On Windows, it's usually UTF-16, I think. But it depends on the file system. – I'm not sure there is an environment variable for that; I only said there might be... just trying to give you some pointers to search further.

Comment: No I am not sure :) But it's not ASCII, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: The below is the workaround for python 3.8.1**

Please modify the bulid-in package source code, named modulefinder.py
and from the very top position, please add below codes:

```
import _locale

_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'utf8'])
```

save it and run again. It should work.

**Sorry below workaround works on python 3.6.9**

I encountered the same issue but I have a workaround to solve the issue:

Remove any codes and comments contain non-ASCII characters from any SOURCE script.

Update:

I found another simple workaround:
Modify your source code file's encoding to your windows default code page.
You can use notepad.exe to open your source code and save as ANSI encoding.

Comment: Thanks for answer, are libraries included?

Comment: According to my test, libraries are not necessary.

Comment: Hmm, interestingly most of the libraries are  working except functools (which is in  standard library). But if there is a library which includes functools, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Also I can't read this file in python, what it has in it?  import functools; f = open(functools.__file__); f.read()

Comment: Hello, I just found the workaround for 3.8.1 version. please try it.

Comment: Thanks you too much, I use Python 3.8 and it works.